# Query many to one backward relation Django

Tags: django, django-models, model

I have these 2 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day_of_week = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

Is it possible for me to use a single query here to get back something like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "full_name": "User name",
   "work_schedule": {
      {
        "day_of_week": 1,
        "start_time": 8:00,
        "end_time": 20:00
      },
      {
        "day_of_week": 2,
        "start_time": 8:00,
        "end_time": 20:00
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A single query does not make much sense, since it would increase the bandwidth significantly, you do this in two queries, one for the `User`, and one for the related `WorkSchedule`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However in this case, I might want to do it for multiple user. So do I have to repeat the query for workschedule for each user? Or should I try to get all the related WorkSchedule and map it with python?

Comment: @LeHongNhat: then you do it still in two queries: one where you fetch the users, and one with the related `WorkSchedule`s of all these `User`s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible

#### models.py

```py
class User(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day_of_week = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

##### serializer.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    work_schedule = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_work_schedule(self, obj):
        working = WorkSchedule.objects.filter(user_id=obj)
        wr =WorkSerializer(working,many=True)
        return wr.data
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkSchedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

##### urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
 
urlpatterns = [
 
    path('', DemoApi.as_view(),name='demo'),
    path('<int:pk>/', DemoApi.as_view(),name='demo'),
]
```

##### views.py

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import User
from .serializers import *

class DemoApi(APIView):
  def get(self, request, pk=None):
    id = pk
    if id is not None:
      try:
        queryset = User.objects.get(pk=id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset)
        return Response({'status': True, "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
      except User.DoesNotExist as e:
        return Response({'status': False, "message": "User dose not exist!"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response({'status': True, "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

##### Postman response for all users

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "work_schedule": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "day_of_week": 1,
                    "start_time": "01:10:08",
                    "end_time": "10:10:22",
                    "user_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "day_of_week": 2,
                    "start_time": "02:10:43",
                    "end_time": "10:10:48",
                    "user_id": 1
                }
            ],
            "full_name": "User1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "work_schedule": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "day_of_week": 1,
                    "start_time": "03:11:06",
                    "end_time": "11:11:18",
                    "user_id": 2
                }
            ],
            "full_name": "User2"
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Postman response for a single user

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "work_schedule": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "day_of_week": 1,
                "start_time": "01:10:08",
                "end_time": "10:10:22",
                "user_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "day_of_week": 2,
                "start_time": "02:10:43",
                "end_time": "10:10:48",
                "user_id": 1
            }
        ],
        "full_name": "User1"
    }
}
```

##### Postman testing urls

```py
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ # for all users
http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/ # for single user
```